# Generate Doxygen Comments

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am generating a large amount of code, and need to make it match a specific coding standard. I am looking for a command line program where I will pass it a file, and it'll automatically add doxygen style comments for parameters and return values, etc.

```
int doSomething(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
    return 42;
}
```

would become something like

```
/**
    @param p1
    @param p2
    @param p3
    @return
*/
int doSomething(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
    return 42;
}
```

Any suggestions? I know many IDEs will do this automatically if you type /** and hit enter, but I would like to do it on the whole code base at once.

Comment: Can't you get your code generator to do that? Will be much easier, than an extra postprocessing step, IMHO.

Comment: I love those 1st time askers that'll never find back to their questions :-D ... Did you mean I'm _writing_ lots of code instead of 'generating' it??